# How to use API Login page in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app, that requires users to login using some 3rd party login API like Terracycle login page.

From API I can infer that If I would have been developing an Web App then it would have been an easy task. I could have used there login form to get user credentials and then once authenticated I would have redirected it to my site link.

But for an android app how do I do the same.
In simple words I want to make a login with Terracycle(or maybe google+) form in android and then try to get the authentication token.

Do I have to use a WebView to open the login form ? 
If I use that how do I stop it to going to redirect url and force it to go to a redirect activity ?
How do I get OAuth 2.0 token then ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to [this Terracycle site](http://www.terracycle.co.uk/).

According to their API http://developers.terracycle.co.uk/devportal/docs/getting_started you will have to display a webview to show the authorisation screen. Then after the user authorises it, the webview will be redirected to the redirect url you provide to them.

You intercept this call with the `WebViewClient`'s [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading) method.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    // handle by yourself
    return true; 
}
```

You then get a code from the code parameter `&code=` which is then sent to the API using

```
POST https://api.terracycle.co.uk/oauth/token
```

This then gives you an access token you can use in all of your requests.

Comment: yup, that the site I was talking about.

Comment: Do I have to parse 'url' parameter in the method to get '&code=' parameter ?

Comment: Yes. Just get everything from `code=` to either the end or the next `&`